# Работа с stdin и stdout дочернего процесса одновременно в lua

Tags: linux, lua, процесс, io

При написании lua скрипта наткнулся на одну вещь: io.popen, судя по [документации](http://www.lua.ru/doc/5.7.html) не может передать одновременно дескрипторы stdin и stdout запускаемого процесса.

Пример проблемного кода:

```
cmdexecute = function(cmd, input)
    local f = io.popen(cmd, "w");
    if tostring(input) ~= nil then
        f:write(tostring(input));
    end;
    local l = f:read("*a");
    f:close();
    return (l);
end;

if cmdexecute('xargs ps', 'aux') ~= nil then
    print 'ps aux что-то выдал';
else
    print 'ps aux промолчал';
end;
```

Результат выполнения:

```
Длинный-длинный вывод ps aux...
ps aux промолчал
```

А должно быть по идее:

```
ps aux что-то выдал
```

Вопрос: как получить дескрипторы и stdin, и stdout из popen? Или, возможно, есть какое-то другое решение задачи, *без* `io.popen`?

Upd: по причине актуальности вопроса поясняю: решения с `ffi` **допустимы**.

Comment: а в чём, собственно, заключается вопрос?

Comment: Пояснил в вопросе

Comment: На основе ответа @Pavel создал модуль: https://github.com/v1993/systemscripting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам должен помочь модуль [`lua-subprocess`](http://luaforge.net/docman/539/5782/subprocess.html)

Функция `subprocess.popen` принимает последним аргументом таблицу с именованными опциями. Среди них есть опции `stdin`, `stdout` и `stderr`, куда можно передать строку (имя файла), число (системный дескриптор файла), файловый объект или специальную константу `subprocess.PIPE`, которая создаст пайп для этого потока и сохранит его в возвращаемом объекте.

Comment: "...для этого потока..." Может быть, всё-таки процесса?

Comment: @val извиняюсь за поздний ответ - но все-таки потока. Речь идет о *потоке данных* (stream), а не о *потоке управления* (thread).

Answer (score 6):

io.popen дает интерфейс к системной posix функции popen, да, она может работать только в одну сторону. В вашем случае писать что то в ps не нужно. Если открыть ее для чтения - она конечно прочитает. Но я так понимаю `ps` у вас только для примера ...

В POSIX для работы с обоими файловыми дескрипторами вызываемого процесса есть только 1 путь. Создание пар сокетов, привязка одного из концов этих соединений к файловым дескрипторам 0 и 1 (`dup2`). После чего выполняется `fork` и дочерний процесс вызывает нужную программу.

В Lua судя по документации подобных средств не предусмотрено. Так что прямой ответ на ваш вопрос - получить и stdin и stdout одновременно невозможно.
Из решений вижу только перенаправление вывода программы в файл и последующее чтение этого файла. Или ввод для программы пишется заранее в файл и подается на вход. И можно еще поэкспериментировать с именованными каналами. `mkfifo` создать именованный канал в файловой системе направить его в программу или запись из программы перенаправить в него и в lua открыть этот канал как обычный файл и попробовать писать/читать.